# Why does this keep adding an extra 1 to my count?

Tags: python

I need to prompt the user for 6 integer inputs, store them and count how many are below 0 and that's the output. But it keeps adding an extra 1 to my count and I'm unsure why.

```py
temp = []
numz = 0
for i in range(6):
    temp.append(int(input('Enter Celcius temperature:\n')))
    for i in temp:
        if i <= 0:
            numz += 1
            break

print(temp) #for ensuring accurate inputs
print('\nNumber of below freezing temperatures:', numz)
```

Example output:

```
[15, 8, -30, -7, -3, 7]
Number of below freezing temperatures: 4
```

Comment: Don't know enough python (any) but you are reusing the `i` variable so it doesn't seem far fetched that that is your issue. Can you change the `for i in temp` to `for j in temp`  and `if j <=0:` and try again?

Comment: Also you are using a nested loop for some reason. Every time a new temperature gets entered the code goes through all the list so far and counting values. The problem is that on subsequent entries, `numz` won't be starting from 0. You need to first build the list of inputs and then count negatives.

Comment: pavel, Thank you for the input. I'm only using a nested loop because I was required to for this. I'm still learning python and this is one of the exercises I had to do. Thank you for the info though. I really appreciate it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inner for loop is unnecessary and changing the value of Numz. Use below code

```
temp = []
numz = 0
for i in range(6):
    i = int(input('Enter Celcius temperature:\n'))
    temp.append(i)
    if i <= 0:
        numz += 1

print(temp)#for ensuring accurate inputs       
print('\nNumber of below freezing temperatures:', numz)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been beating my head over this.

Comment: You are using the same variable `i` for multiple purposes. Surely not a good idea and will probably not yield the right result.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the indentation of your for loop

```
for j in range(6):
    temp.append(int(input('Enter Celcius temperature:\n')))
for i in temp:
    if i < 0:
        numz += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As @pavel commented, your code is **logically** wrong. In each outer iteration, you are adding a new number to `temp`. You then do an inner loop which sums over all negative numbers in `temp`.

As an alternative, you can simply increment `numz` each time the input is <= 0:

```
numz = 0
for i in range(6):
    x = int(input('Enter Celcius temperature:\n'))
    numz += (x <= 0) # implicit Bool --> Int
 print(numz)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's why your code is incorrect.

In the second `for` loop, as soon as a non-positive value is encountered, it breaks out of the loop, so it's not counting the number of non-positive values in `temp`, but is actually counting the same value (the first non-positive value) 4 times (since it exists in the list for 4 iterations).

I've add print statements to your code which you can run so it's easier to understand what I've explained above:

```py
temp = []
numz = 0
for i in range(6):
    temp.append(int(input('\nEnter Celcius temperature:\n')))
    print(f"\nValue of temp: {temp}")
    for i in temp:
        print(f"Value of i: {i}")
        if i <= 0:
            print(f"i = {i} which is negative or 0.")
            print("Incrementing numz and breaking out of the loop.")
            numz += 1
            print(f"Value of numz: {numz}")
            break

print('\nNumber of below freezing temperatures:', numz)
```

And here's what you could do instead.

```py
temp = []
numz = 0
for i in range(6):
    temp_input = int(input('\nEnter Celcius temperature:\n'))
    if i <= 0:
        print(f"i = {i} which is negative or 0. Incrementing numz.")
        numz += 1
        print(f"Value of numz: {numz}")
    temp.append(temp_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions give fixes, here is the reason for your unexpected output.
The core of the issues is that your loop are nested. You technically do not need 2 loops, but what happens is:

- read 15

  - add 15 to the `temp` array
  - go through each item in `temp`, none in negative, `numz` is 0
- read 8

  - same as for 15
- read -30

  - add -30 to the `temp` array
  - the inner loop goes through all elements of `temp`, find -30, `numz` in now 1
- read -7

  - add -7 to `temp`
  - the inner loop goes through all elements of `temp`, find -30, **stops there** because of the `break`, `numz` is now 2

For each new element, the same happens. The values of all elements after the fist negative are not relevant anymore.

In short, your output gives (in a convoluted way) the number of elements in the array, after and including the first negative element.

Answer (score 0):

Second for loop is not needed. Every time user input something that loop will run from `temp[0]` to `temp[i]` which is redundant. This is also the reason why `numz` is always one greater than you are expecting.

```py
temp = []
numz = 0
for i in range(6):
      temp.append(int(input('Enter Celcius temperature:\n')))
      #for i in temp: #this loop is redundant
      if temp[i] <= 0:  #this is what you wan't to do
        numz += 1

print(temp)#for ensuring accurate inputs       
print('\nNumber of below freezing temperatures:', numz)
```